# How to make click listener listen to all items in enum class for web intent

Tags: android, kotlin, enums

My click listener seems to only allow me to use the `urlId` for 1 item in my enum classs. i.e. `Services.ItemBing.urlId`. How can the click listener be modified so that it listens to all the items in the enum class rather than just the "Bing URL" item and to have to make a click listener for every item individually?

```
enum class Websites(@StringRes val textResId: Int, val urlId: String) {
    ItemBing(R.string.bing, "https://www.bing.com/")
    ItemGoogle(R.string.google, "https://www.google.com/")
    ItemYahoo(R.string.yahoo, "https://www.yahoo.com/")
}

val clickListener: (Websites) -> String = {
    startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(Services.ItemBing.urlId)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parameter intent in the enum class

```kotlin
    enum class Websites(@StringRes val textResId: Int, val urlId: String) {
        ItemBing(R.string.bing, "https://www.bing.com/"),
        ItemGoogle(R.string.google, "https://www.google.com/"),
        ItemYahoo(R.string.yahoo, "https://www.yahoo.com/");

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlId))

    }
```

And whenever you'll have a Websites enum you could use the intent parameter to get the intent based on the enum.

for exemple :

```kotlin
val clickListener: (Websites) -> Unit = {
    startActivity(it.intent)
}
```

and even without all that, your clickListener method is wrong.

You can access to the current websites passed in argument with `it` :

```kotlin
val clickListener: (Websites) -> Unit = {
    startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(it.urlId)))
}
```